# Blank line gets removed in HTML mail -> how to add <br> after blank lines

Tags: php, carriage-return

In order to maintain formatting in an HTML mail, I'm looking for some php code to change a blank line into `<br>`.

For example, the original text:

```
Line 1
Line 2

Line 3
```

Should turn into:

```
Line 1
Line 2
< br >
Line 3
```

I tried `nl2br`, but that functions add `<br>` after every line, not just the blank lines.

Any help would be appreciated.

David

Comment: Try using `<p>` around paragraphs rather than `<br>` to make blank lines in emails.

Comment: I don't think the down vote was fair.  The text comes from a text file. It has blank lines which need to be maintained in the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analysed the message contents byte by byte and found a solution.

To maintain a line break in an HTML email, use the code below:

```
$TheMessage=str_replace("\r\n\r\n", "<br>",$TheMessage);
```

It is the double 'carriage return & line feed' right after each other that is the key to the solution.